# Highcharts: Selecting single series from plot with multiple series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a plot that is similar to the one shown in this JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r76kmsfr/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        legend: {
            align: "left"
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: "Winter 2012-2013",
            // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
            // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
            // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 4), 0.28],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 27), 0.2],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 2), 0.28],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 26), 0.28],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 29), 0.47],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 11), 0.79],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 26), 0.72],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 3), 1.02],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 11), 1.12],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 25), 1.2],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 11), 1.18],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 11), 1.19],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 1), 1.85],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 5), 2.22],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 19), 1.15],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 3), 0]
            ]
        }, {
            name: "Winter 2013-2014",
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 1), 1.66],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 10), 1.8],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 19), 1.76],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 25), 2.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19), 2.41],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 30), 2.05],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 14), 1.7],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 24), 1.1],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 0]
            ]
        }, {
            name: "Winter 2014-2015",
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 6), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 4), 1.6],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 17), 2.55],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 24), 2.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 4), 2.5],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 14), 2.42],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 6), 2.74],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 14), 2.62],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 24), 2.6],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 2), 2.81],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 12), 2.63],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 28), 2.77],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 5), 2.68],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 10), 2.56],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 15), 2.39],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 20), 2.3],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 5), 2],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 10), 1.85],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 15), 1.49],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 23), 1.08]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

What I would like to do is allow a user to click on one of these series, which would hide the other series on the plot. How do I do that?

Example: Clicking on the black series would hide the green and blue series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is hide all the series in click and show show the one that is clicked on. I have included the code you need below and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8hrc9d8/) . This way you show the graph the user clicks on. In addition you could have a 'show all' button, which redraws the whole chart. Hope this helps.

```
plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
             series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                      var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

                      $(chart.series).each(function(){
                          this.setVisible(false, false);
                      });
                      this.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try implement something like this

```
         series:{
                events: {
                        legendItemClick: function (e) {


                            var seriesArr=$('#container').highcharts().series;
                            var visible = this.visible;
                            var index = this.index;
                            for(var i=0; i<seriesArr.length;i++)
                            {
                                if(i!=index)
                                {
                                    seriesArr[i].setVisible(false, false);
                                }
                            }

                            this.visible=false;  


                        }
                    }
        }
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgonzalez315/4jsgo8c9/5/

I hope this help!

Comment: Small improvement: second click on the legend will show other series back: http://jsfiddle.net/4jsgo8c9/7/

Comment: Thanks, nice improvement!